# Using Dates as a SQL Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of data that goes quite some time back, but I only want to results in my query for the last 13 weeks. There is a date column in that table.

I can use

```
SELECT DATEADD(Week, -13, GETDATE())
```

to get the date of 13 weeks back as a separate query - but I am having trouble linking that into the initial select to only return me the last 13 weeks of data.  I have used that query as the data should refresh every day to go back 13 weeks to that date.

Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could put this query into a procedure as well if you are ever looking for a different look back number; say you only want to grab 10 weeks back, or 15 weeks back. Just set a parameter for weeklookback or something like that

Answer (score 3):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE date_field >
    (SELECT DATEADD(Week, - 13, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused on what your issue is. You should be able to use the dateadd() in your where clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATECOLUMNTOCOMPARE >  DATEADD(WEEK,-13,GETDATE())
```